# Como hacer un put en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Buenas estoy haciendo una api con la cual quiero actualizar una propiedad llamada favorito que es un booleano. EL método que con el intento actualizar ese campo es el siguiente

```
public static void actualizarPdfDAL(int id, bool fav)
        {
            clsMyConnection clsMyConnection = new clsMyConnection();
            SqlConnection conexion = clsMyConnection.getConnection();
            SqlCommand miComando = new SqlCommand();

            try
            {
                miComando.CommandText = $"UPDATE PDFs" +
                    $"SET favorito = @fav WHERE idPdf = @id";

                miComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                miComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fav", fav);
                miComando.Connection = conexion;
                miComando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally { conexion.Close(); }
        }
```

El problema es que me devuelve una expción en la que me dice

**Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'favorito'.'**

Puede que tenga algo que ver que en C# el tipo es booleano y en sql server es bit?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es muy sencilla. Un despiste y es que la concatenación del comando estaba mal falataba un espacio entre PDFs y SET

```
miComando.CommandText = $"UPDATE PDFs " +
                    $"SET favorito = @fav WHERE idPdf = @id";
```

Este sería el resultado. No me lo creo que por esta tonteria un mareo de cabeza enorme

Comment: Es más común de lo que crees, así que relaaaax~ Mira el conocimiento en debugging que has adquirido por esa experiencia :) ahora prestarás más atención a los espacios en blanco en concatenaciones. Saludos y sigue desarrollando con todo el power!!! PD: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada luego de 24 horas, así ayudarás con la buena salud del sitio por efecto de preguntas resueltas.

Comment: Muchas gracias en cuanti pueda comento como respuesta. Le daremos con todo

Comment: Un placer colaborar, sigue progresando :D